# rails association same column name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have my controller

```
@post = Post.joins(:customer).select("customers.*,posts.*").find params[:id]
```

Both the relations have `created_at` How can i print both dates as `registered date` and `posted date`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to select manually all columns of each tables:

```
# this is fine
@post = Post.joins(:customer).find(params[:id])
# this is better (will not raise a RecordNotFound if no record found)
@post = Post.joins(:customer).where(id: params[:id]).first
```

In your view, you can access the attributes like this:

```
Post was created at: <%= @post.created_at %>
Customer registered at: <%= @post.customer.created_at %>
```

This code is relying on the fact that the column `created_at` is the date when the Post was created / the Customer registered. This might be false sometimes, if you import a list of existing Customers for example

Comment: so i have to add column as registered_at and posted_at in relations. I cant use existing created_at right?

Comment: Yes you can use them but it is not recommended. I'll update my answer

Comment: No, `@post` is the Post object persisted in your DB. `@post.customer` will return the Customer object associated with the Post, doing `@post.customer.username` will display its username ;)

Comment: That was my silly mistake i corrected it. You solved my problem